# How to fix Derby issue for Apache Netbeans IDE 15

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, derby, netbeans-15

Unable to start server for Derby in IDE 15.

Tried to use Derby version 14, didn't work. Tried to change the location of the folder, didn't work.
[image: Java DB Properties]

When I press start server, it just hangs there, does no further processing.

Comment: When I press start server, it just hangs there, does no further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Unresolved NetBeans Bug [NETBEANS-3424 Unable to use Derby DB version 10.15.1.3 in Netbeans 11.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3424) looks relevant to your problem, though you are using different software releases of Derby, Java and NetBeans and your issue is with starting the server rather than establishing a connection.

I can reproduce the connection failure issue on NetBeans 15 using JDK 19 and Derby 10.16.1.1. After selecting the *sample* database connection **jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample [app on APP]** and selecting **Connect...** from the context menu this error is displayed:

[image: DerbyError]

Although that linked bug report is open and unresolved, a helpful user posted a workaround in the comments so that a suitable driver can be found:

- In the **Services** panel in NetBeans select the entry **Databases > Drivers > Java DB (Embedded)**, right click and select **Customize...** from the context menu.
- The **Customize JDBC Driver** window will be displayed.
- Click the **Add...** button three times to add the jars **derbytools.jar**, **derbyshared.jar** and **derbyoptionaltools.jar** from the **lib** directory of your Derby installation (which is named **C:\Apache\db-derby-10.16.1.1-bin** in my case, but yours is almost certainly something else).
- After doing that your **Customize JDBC Driver** window for your **Java DB (Embedded)** driver should look similar to this:

  [image: AddedJars1]
- Similarly, for the **Databases > Drivers > Java DB (Network)** entry add the jars **derbytools.jar** and **derbyshared.jar** so that your **Customize JDBC Driver** window looks like this:

  [image: AddedJars2]

After adding those jars to the two drivers you should immediately be able to connect to the **APP** database using the connection **jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample [app on APP]**, and view its tables:

[image: ConnectionToAPP]

Notes:

- You are using Java 8 which is unsupported in NetBeans 15. Update your IDE to use JDK 11 or greater.
- You don't need to explicitly start the server by selecting **Databases > Java DB > Start Server**. Instead, just select **Connect...** for **jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample [app on APP]**